# Following service and dao layer approach in play framework will reduce play's main features?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I am developing a web application using play framework 2.4.x and I followed Service layer and DAO layer approach after controller. Does this approach make any issues with play's main feature like asynchronous and thread pooling and others? I came across lot of sample applications calling db connections from controller itself.

May I use the above approach or not?

Comment: I use your approach with service layer and DAOs without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I use DAOs, etc, without a problem.  Make sure you're using futures!

For example, don't have a DAO method like `List<Foo> findAll()` - instead, have `F.Promise<List<Foo>> findAll()`

If you're using different thread pools you'll need to make the necessary executor service available to your DAOs and services - in this case, ideally, you would inject a supplier for the executor service.  A default implementation would simply be

```
public class MyExecutionProvider implements Supplier<ExecutionContext> {
    public ExecutionContext get() {
        return HttpExecution.defaultContext();
    }
}
```

with the necessary binding registered for the DI framework.

The resulting DAO would then look something like

```
@Singleton
public class FooDao {

    private final Supplier<ExecutionContext> ec;

    @Inject
    public FooDao(final Supplier<ExecutionContext> ec) {
        this.ec = ec;
    }

    public F.Promise<List<Foo>> findAll() {
        return F.Promise.promise(() -> // some database call,
                                 ec.get());
    }
}
```

A controller using this DAO can then use the typical asynchronous approach.

```
public class FooController extends Controller {
    private final FooDao fooDao;

    @Inject
    public FooController(final FooDao fooDao) {
        this.fooDao = fooDao;
    }

    public F.Promise<Result> getAll() {
        return fooDao.findAll()
                     .map(Json::toJson)
                     .(Results::ok)
    }
}
```

Adjust for Scala, use of interfaces, preferred architecture, etc as necessary.